# How to customize the url of a field in views?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a view that displays product images using a jcarousel. In the view, I have a jCarousel format and it displays fields. In the Fields section, I'm displaying Content: Image. I want to link the image to a specific url. I can modify it using Rewrite Results and selecting Output this field as a link.

According to the answer I got from [how to make a field in a view be the link destination to another field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8991/how-to-make-a-field-in-a-view-be-the-link-destination-to-another-field) & http://64sqft.danapellerin.com/2011/06/07/drupal-custom-cck-field-tokens-in-views. Views takes into consideration the order in which your fields are in the view. The taxonomy field that you want to use as a token needs to be reordered above the field you want to use the token in the url.

**Things I've tried**:

- I tried content:category (which is my taxonomy field), and hid it so it wouldn't display. In the field's replacement patterns it gave me [taxonomy_catalog] & [taxonomy_catalog-tid]. I tried [taxonomy_catalog] but the replacement gave me the text from taxonomy description.
- I tried Content: All taxonomy terms, but it gave me the name of the term instead of the ID.

How can I modify the rewrite to include the taxonomy term id associated with the node?

Comment: Have you tried adding the taxonomy term as a relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the way that Content: All taxonomy terms required a rewrite to [term_node_tid-tid]. Otherwise it would display the term name instead of the tid.